# How to hide your Wifi Hotspot from unwanted devices

Tags: wifi-hotspot, hidden

Device : Galaxy S5
Version : 5.6

I have a request

How can I hotspot my 4G but I only want to select who can see the network on wi-fi

And for other people when they search wifi they don't see it

Anyone answer

Answer (score 0):

Keep your ssid hidden, after creating the wifi hotspot. Just tell your friends and others the ssid. No one else would be able to see it.

Comment: This answer begs more detail: how to keep the SSID hidden on Android's hotspot setting?